# Django is installed but it couldn't run - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django

I installed django on my mac but i couldn't run my project as because this issue:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I don't know about this, The problem is i couldn't import django on my system but tried this way too...

```
(my_project) my_project % python
Python 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:04:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>> import django
>>>
```

It's all fine, But i dont no the problem where is?

Comment: presumably you are not running your other project within your venv (that you are running the shell in)

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have many python versions on your Mac, for example the Python version in your virtualenv is different from the default version of python.

Maybe you downloaded the django framework to other version.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, And i check it first...

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python3.6 version and my django version is 3.2(LTS)... It's not issue..

Comment: No @mr.faceless, this answer is not about the Django version. This answer is saying you might have multiple versions of Python, and that you installed Django to one version but run the app in another version.

Comment: How can i fix it Gino???

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `pip list` See if you have Django

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, Django on the list

Comment: But still i got this same error